# Dar color a puntos en base a contar

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy graficando el consumo de litros (y) por día (x) en un proyecto ,pero estoy interesado en darle a color a los puntos solo cuando cuente mas de 2 consumos en cualquier día, como por ejemplo los de la imagen adjunta, no logro dar con una función que me ayude ¿Pueden Apoyarme? Gracias de Antemano

`ggplot(data,aes(x=Dia,y = Litros))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~PERIODO)`

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas crear una nueva dimensión en tu gráfica para la situación de consumos que se repiten en un mismo día/periodo. La idea básica sería, agrupar los datos por Período/Día y contar la cantidad de consumos. Resolver esto con `tidyverse`, es relativamente sencillo. En primer lugar, armemos una muestra similar a tus datos:

```
set.seed(2019)
data <- data.frame(Dia=sample(1:30,20*12, replace=TRUE), 
                   Litros=sample(10:75, 20*12, replace = TRUE),
                   PERIODO=1:12)
```

Lo primero sería generar esta nueva columna:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(PERIODO, Dia) %>% 
  mutate(multiple=ifelse(length(Dia)>1, "Si", "No")) %>% 
  ungroup() -> data

data

# A tibble: 240 x 4
     Dia Litros PERIODO multiple
   <int>  <int>   <int> <chr>   
 1    25     35       1 No      
 2    29     23       2 No      
 3    10     15       3 No      
 4     5     75       4 No      
 5    13     19       5 No      
 6    17     59       6 No      
 7    24     41       7 No      
 8    23     63       8 Si      
 9    29     16       9 Si      
10    12     21      10 Si      
# … with 230 more rows
```

Hemos generado la nueva columna `multiple` que nos dice si el consumo es de un día que tiene más de uno. Lo siguiente es "mapear" esta variable a una nueva dimensión gráfica, en este caso `color`

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Dia, y = Litros, color=multiple)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~PERIODO)
```

Salida final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]